# Writing multiple checkbox values to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write multiple checkbox values to a field in the database seperated by commas but it won't work. I'm using emplode and explode but it only writes one of the selected values. Meaning if i select 2 options, it would only write one. Here is my code below:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
include_once '..../..php';

$emailtemp = $_POST['email'];
         $ordernumber2 = substr($emailtemp, 0, 3);
         $ordernumber1 = RAND(1,100);         
         $ordernumber = $ordernumber2.$ordernumber1;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$services = implode(",",$_POST["services"]);

$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_orders (streetaddress, floor, building, apartment, area, phone, block, avenue, ordernumber, email, service) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', $_POST['streetaddress'], $_POST['floor'], $_POST['building'], $_POST['apartment'], $_POST['area'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['block'], $_POST['avenue'], $ordernumber, $_POST['email'], $services);
$results =  $statement->execute();
if($results){
header('location:../thankyou.php');

}else{
        header('location:../error.php');
}
?>
```

Also, my form:

```
<form method="post" action="includes/guestorder.php" name="GuestForm" id="GuestForm" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return Confirm('Are you sure of the details entered?');">

    <br>
    <center>
    Please choose the services you require<br><br>

    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="electrician" checked> Electrician  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="health" type="checkbox" value="health"> Health Technician &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="ac"> Air Conditioning Technician&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="computer" id="computer" type="checkbox" value="computer"> Computer Technician&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="satelite"> Satelite Service Technician&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="blacksmith"> Blacksmith &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="aliminium"> Aliminium Technician &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="carpenter"> Carpenter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="housedecor"> Interior Designer & House Decorations&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="gardener"> Gardener&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="ceramics"> Ceramics&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="painter"> Painter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>

    <?php
         echo "<br><fieldset>";
         echo "<legend>Your Details & Information</legend>";
         echo "Street Address:<br /> <input name='streetaddress' id='streetaddress' type='text' required /><br />";
         echo "Building/House:<br /> <input name='building' id='building' type='text' required /><br />";
         echo "Avenue:<br /> <input name='avenue' id='avenue' type='text'><br />";
         echo "Block:<br /> <input name='block' id='block' type='text' required /><br />";
         echo "Floor:<br /> <input name='floor' id='floor' type='text'><br />";
         echo "Apartment:<br /> <input name='apartment' id='apartment' type='text'><br />";
         echo "Area:<br /> <input name='area' id='area' type='text' required /><br />";
         echo "Email Address:<br /> <input name='email' id='email' type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$' required /><br />";
         echo "Phone Number:<br /> <input name='phone' id='phone' type='text' pattern='[569][0-9]{7}' required /><br />"; 
         echo "</fieldset>";
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the first part meant to be a singe PHP file? It has multiple ini_set and error_reporting lines.

Comment: Why using so much &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: Hi there! I fixed up some of your formatting to make it easier to read. Please be mindful of keeping even spacing in posts as it makes understanding what's happening much easier, the same is true in your scripts too!

Answer (score 0):

use it with quotes for $services like '"'.$services.'"'

```
$statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', 
$_POST['streetaddress'],$_POST['floor'], $_POST['building'],
$_POST['apartment'], $_POST['area'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['block'], 
$_POST['avenue'], $ordernumber, $_POST['email'], '"'.$services.'"');
```

Comment: The `bind_param` function needs an actual `PHP variable` rather than a value (expression).  There is no `bindValue` (PDO) equivalent in `mysqli`. i.e. it will not work unless a list of variables is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what you are trying to achieve, because left for me, i would advice on another table holding all services, then a second table where you have guests ids saved with matching selected services but if we want to go by what you have, just quote your list.
Preferably single quotes.

```
$statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', $_POST['streetaddress'],
$_POST['floor'], $_POST['building'], $_POST['apartment'], $_POST['area'], 
$_POST['phone'], $_POST['block'], $_POST['avenue'], $ordernumber, 
$_POST['email'], "'".$services."'");
```